# Patch pyopenssl for sslv3 issue

Tags: python-2.7, debian, pip, pyopenssl, urllib3

I got a problem on a Debian 8 system with python 2.7.9-2 amd64:

```
    marius@pydev:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib$ pip search doo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 356, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2476, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2190, in load
    ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 22, in <module>
    import requests, six
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 73, in <module>
    ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3: OpenSSL.SSL.SSLv3_METHOD,
**AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PROTOCOL_SSLv3'**
```

I checked into the lib and tried to patch /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py

```
    from .. import connection
from .. import util

__all__ = ['inject_into_urllib3', 'extract_from_urllib3']

# SNI only *really* works if we can read the subjectAltName of certificates.
HAS_SNI = SUBJ_ALT_NAME_SUPPORT

# Map from urllib3 to PyOpenSSL compatible parameter-values.
_openssl_versions = {
    ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23: OpenSSL.SSL.SSLv23_METHOD,
    **ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3: OpenSSL.SSL.SSLv3_METHOD,**
    ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1: OpenSSL.SSL.TLSv1_METHOD,
}
_openssl_verify = {
    ssl.CERT_NONE: OpenSSL.SSL.VERIFY_NONE,
    ssl.CERT_OPTIONAL: OpenSSL.SSL.VERIFY_PEER,
    ssl.CERT_REQUIRED: OpenSSL.SSL.VERIFY_PEER
                       + OpenSSL.SSL.VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT,
}
```

Could someone enlighten me how I can fix this? It would be super awesome if someone had a clue. I googled the issue and only found incomplete patches and it's messy. Probably a case for the bug tracker once this is fixed, too. I have this issue for all Python packages.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This is actually an issue with `urllib3`, not with `pyopenssl`. Debian [lately compiles OpenSSL without SSLv3 support](https://launchpad.net/debian/+source/openssl/1.0.1j-1), and `urllib3` just assumed that support was there.

The issue was [fixed in commit b9b3b0102](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/commit/b9b3b0102ead7ad8ad086c39737f22ddefa7e626) which is part of the 1.10 release of `urllib3`.

As you are using `urllib3` as part of `requests`, which in turn is used by `pip`, it should be enough to update to a recent version of `requests`. As of writing, the current version is 2.6.0 which contains the fix:

```
# pip install requests==2.6.0
```

You might encounter a problem upgrading `requests`, because of the chicken-egg problem. To fix this, you can try to temporarily remove the `pyopenssl` package, upgrade `requests` and reinstall `pyopenssl`.

Additionally you might want to use the following line to update `pip` before trying to update `requests`:

```
# sudo easy_install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: In my custom script I solved it by moving to PROTOCOL_TLSv1 (instead of PROTOCOL_SSLv3). Thanks for hint @sk1p

Comment: ```sudo pip install --upgrade requests``` did the trick on debian 8.6 for  me

Comment: I have version .21 of requests and still the issue. Tried exactly what you did but did not work

Answer (score 47):

Another way to fix the problem is to use

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade pip
```

and use pip normally afterwards

Comment: Just to be clear, what worked for me was the above, and then run 'pip install requests==2.6.0'

Comment: Confirmed! this works in conjunction with `pip install requests==2.6.0` as stated by @Oliver Block. Many thanks!

Comment: Note that you don't want to use `sudo` if you're in a virtualenv!

Answer (score 14):

I've received the same error.
In conjunction with the previous answers:

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade pip
```

I've also had to run:

```
sudo pip uninstall pyopenssl
sudo pip install mozdownload
```

This fixed my error, maybe it can help others. I came here by googling:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PROTOCOL_SSLv3'

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this problem today with Ansible. I solved it with:

`pip uninstall pyopenssl`

maybe this will help someone else in the same situation

Comment: Applies to same situation in docker also.

Comment: This solved my problem, previously I applied sk1p answer with no luck. I didn't need to install  mzdownload as AlexTartan suggests.

Answer (score 3):

I received this error after an upgrade from Ubuntu 14 to 16. The upgrade changed some Python paths, which broke some core packages. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36082675/247542) essentially fixed it for me.

```
sudo apt-get purge python-pkg-resources
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo rm -Rf /usr/local/bin/pip
sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install -U pip
```

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same problems and I just uninstall the version of `requests` and install the exact version by using the following command.

`pip install requests==2.6.0`

then it works

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this on a new Xenial and was unsuccessful w/many answers I had seen (some I really didn't try because most of my software was more current).  What finally solved it for me was:  sudo pip install requests --upgrade ... which is just a twist on the other request upgrade recommendation.