# Can import theano.tensor but not theano.tensor.fft

Tags: python, python-2.7, keras, theano

I have default and anaconda python, theano is installed in conda moreover it was also part of anaconda for keras. I am trying to exec a python file from another folder as `python ----` and everything is ok except `from theano.tensor.fft import ifft` where it says `no module named theano.tensor.fft` I have added `PYTHONPATH` I have separately added theano in site-package but i can not figure out why it can not import module, please note that I can `import theano.tensor` I am trying to run MarcBS/keras caffe2keras.py

this is what I got when trying to install theano

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import requests, six
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 70, in <module>
    ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3: OpenSSL.SSL.SSLv3_METHOD,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PROTOCOL_SSLv3'
```

Comment: You need the developer branch of theano (0.9). I'm assuming you only have 0.8.

Comment: yes I do have only theano 0.8.2 I just checked, let me install 0.9

Comment: I have added the issue in edit , as it was too long in comment, please provide suggestion

Comment: Sorry it was pip issue just solved as given in http://stackoverflow.com/a/29081240/2343086

Comment: Nope it do not work even with theano 0.9